# neo4j session object leaks, neo4j spark connector

Tags: apache-spark, memory-leaks, neo4j, pagerank

I am working on `neo4j-spark` connector for implementing PageRank algorithms. When I run the following command:

```
val g = Neo4jGraph.loadGraph(sc, "Customer", Seq("transactionid"), "Products")
```

I am getting the below mentioned error:

> ERROR session: Neo4j Session object leaked, please ensure that your
>   application calls the `close` method on Sessions before disposing of
>   the objects. org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to
>   process request: ClosedChannelException buffer:

along with multiple error lines.

When I am trying the same line with other variables which has less nodes and relationships, it works fines. How can I get it resolved?

Comment: Which version did you use?

Comment: Thanks Michael for such a quick reply. Here are the versions
Spark version - 1.6.2
Neo4j version- 3.0.1

Comment: Hi Michael, now there's one more error in the same about multiple sessions. I am pasting the error here.
ERROR session: Neo4j Session object leaked, please ensure that your application calls the `close` method on Sessions before disposing of the objects.org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: You are using a session from multiple locations at the same time, which is not supported. If you want to use multiple threads, you should ensure that each session is used by only one thread at a time. One way to do that is to give each thread its own dedicated session.
Kindly see.